# git hooks: get list of files changed after a pull

Tags: git, githooks

I'm trying to create a git hook that checks if there were any updates to a specific folder in the repository. For instance, let's say I am interested in the `/public` folder. Some colleague makes a change to that folder and that change is on the master branch. I still had not pulled those changes and go ahead and run `git pull` on master. I'd want a hook that prints a message notifying that changes were made to the `/public` folder.

I guessed the right hook would be `post-merge`, but I am not quite sure how to check which files changed, since we do not know how many new commits there were. If I was able to process git's output from `git pull`, that'd be quite straightforward but I don't think hooks have access to the output of the command that fired them.

Comment: If I had to do this, I'd have wrapped `git pull` in a helper function/script. But I'm curious about a hook solution, if one is possible.

Comment: As a first pass, your `post-merge` could just be `git diff --name-only HEAD^1 HEAD^2`.  Filter that to check for the directory you care about.  You might also want to check for octopus-merge, but that gets you started.

Comment: @WilliamPursell could you explain the `HEAD^1 HEAD^2` part? which references are those supposed to be? If I run this I just get `fatal: ambiguous argument 'HEAD^2': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.`

Comment: After the merge, `HEAD^1` refers to the first parent, and `HEAD^2` refers to the second parent.  (For an octopus merge, there will be more than 2 parents.)  If you refer to HEAD^2 that while HEAD is not a merge commit, the ambiguous argument is an expected error.

Answer (score 0):

You can check changed files with diff-tree between the two last heads like blew:

```
git diff-tree -r HEAD@{1} HEAD
```

if you don't need the commit id you can add `--name-only`.

Answer (score 0):

Too long for a comment: I am not sure why you need a hook to automate, but if you only need the information, you could do

update the origin which you assume has changed

```
git fetch origin
```

Just check what changed between your version and the remote version

```
git diff mybranch origin/mybranch --stat
 file1.txt      |   84 +
 file2.txt      |  156 +-
 file3.txt      |   90 +-
 file4.txt      |  418 ++--
```

(It seems, `git pull --dry-run --verbose` displays too little information.)